# Priority sequence column in diagnosis_icd

Tags: mimic-iii

The order in the sequence column is related to the patient and based on priority. Priority of patients in critical care medicine are related to triage which is a scoring system including:

1. the severity of the clinical condition
2. the urgency of the clinical condition

Examples are the Manchester Triage System.

Besides that, patients are scored for reimbursement, which is very much influenced by the location and setting you work in.

Scoring severity of disease by priority and by reimbursement rules are frequently different. Patients can have from chronic diseases, requiring a huge amount of budget, but are not severe in the context of a critical care condition.

Which "priority" logics or rules are used in MIMIC?