# diagnoses_icd.sequence in MIMIC-III: does the order matter aside from the primary diagnosis?

Tags: mimic-iii

The column `diagnoses_icd.sequence`, according to the [documentation](https://mimic.physionet.org/mimictables/diagnoses_icd/):

> provides the order in which the ICD diagnoses relate to the patient. ICD diagnoses are ordered by priority.

Does the order really matter aside from the primary diagnosis (i.e. does the `diagnoses_icd.sequence` matter when `diagnoses_icd.sequence > 1`)?

I see `diagnoses_icd.sequence` has values that range from 1 to 39:

```
SELECT distinct(sequence),  COUNT(*)  
FROM  mimiciii.diagnoses_icd 
GROUP BY sequence
ORDER BY   sequence ASC  ;
```

[image]

Comment: This questions looks like it may be a duplicate of http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6303/priority-sequence-column-in-diagnosis-icd

Comment: @tomp They are pretty close indeed: to paraphrase, this question -> "does the order matter after 2"; the other question -> "how was the order decided?". I guess this question is a subset of the other one.

Comment: Thanks Franck, I'll update you on both points when we have a clear answer from the coders.

Comment: i wonder the answer too, could you share with me? Thanks

Comment: Hi Jeanine, you should add this to the comments area.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/6367)